# Reviving a lost language

Tags: discussion

A while ago I did something rather stupid.

After I added a Brain-Flueue flag to the ruby implementation of Brain-Flak I went ahead and deleted the old Brain-Flueue repository.  This made sense at the time because the new Brain-Flueue was better in every possible way, and the old one was preventing me from tab completing in my current directory.

Now I realized this was not a good idea, because I would like to add Brain-Flueue to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot) challenge at some time.  But the new shiny interpreter post-dates the challenge and since it is an [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) question non-competing languages are disallowed.

However, through some convoluted shenanigans I have managed to recover a copy of the interpreter unchanged with all of its git history.

If I publish an unchanged copy of this interpreter online will Brain-Flueue answers still be non-competing?

Comment: [Related, arguably a duplicate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11054/62131).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that if you `git push` from your local repository to a new GitHub repository then no-one will be able to tell the difference. If you hadn't brought it up yourself, it wouldn't even have been an issue.

Comment: And why would it be one now? If the language's timestamp on GH is predating the challenge, then no-one can prove it's postdating it, and I don't think a meta post is enough to warrant non-competitiveness by itself.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, *issue* in the sense of *question under discussion*.

Answer (score 1):

## No. Go ahead and answer

The language was made with the interpreter before the challenge. Add a note on the repo about what happened. Especially with the git-history then you have proof.

Comment: I would like to point out that you [can spoof git history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895453/how-do-i-make-a-git-commit-in-the-past).

Comment: @wheat yes but you can do a lot of things to loophole rules